# Pushing a commit in git when local repo has not already merged origin HEAD

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose that my local repository is currently one commit behind the origin. Suppose that I commit in my local repository a change that is not conflicting with the origin. How can I push this change to the origin without first pulling/merging changes from the origin?

Comment: Why can't you do a pull first?

Comment: Because I do not want to get the remote changes locally just now, since there was committed a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you're getting rejected for non-fast-forward push, and you have your reasons not to 
want to pull the latest update from the remote. I think it's obvious you need to branch off
your changes.

So lets create a a branch at the common point, HEAD~n, in your case HEAD~1:

```
git branch myfeat HEAD~1
```

Then fast-forward it:

```
git checkout myfeat
git merge master
```

Now the new branch has a common point, so just:

```
git push origin myfeat
```

The remote repo now looks like this:

```
--X---X--X--Xbug      (master)
          \
           \--Xfeat   (myfeat)
```

Now others can merge/rebase your feature. Ultimately you'll have to either fix the bug and pull it locally, or you devise a slightly different workflow as you are keeping a custom local master.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you described, but I guess what you want is:

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

The above command will merge your local repo with remote repo gracefully(without creating a merge commit) and push your local commits to the remote.

Comment: That will still get him the bug locally, no?!

Comment: I posted this answer before the OP post his comment. Anyway, I still insist this is the correct way to resolve the problem, since there's a bug, you must fix the bug. Merge your changes with the remote commit(by **rebase** ing on the remote commit), fix that bug and commit & push.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible he wants to push to the remote purely to have a backup of his changes, if that is the case he could do it with

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/some_branchname_not_in_use
```

I generally use `trash/somebranchname` for these things so that it's obvious the purpose.